# Change Page Number Font Size, using {myheadings}?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I've a problem. When I use this command to set the font size of the page numbering ( `\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}` ), all page numbers in TOC turns footnotesize too. How can I solve this?

**[MWE]** This is the preamble of the main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{6,0,111}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,125,0}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering ÍNDICE}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}[0em]{\smallskip}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subparagraph}[0em]{\smallskip\itshape}
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace} %numbered
{} %numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.5mm]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage{units}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{5mm}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0mm}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0mm}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{txfonts}

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
%\titlelabel{\theparagraph.\quad}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\uppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalsize}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubparagraph.}{1em}{}


\begin{document}

% TOC
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

% MISC
\section{Sec One}

\subsection{Subsec One}
\subsection{Subsec Two}
\subsection{Subsec Three}

\newpage
\section{Sec Two}

\subsection{Subsec One}
\subsection{Subsec Two}
\subsection{Subsec Three}

\newpage
\section{Sec Three}

\subsection{Subsec One}
\subsection{Subsec Two}
\subsection{Subsec Three}

\newpage
\section{Sec Four}

\subsection{Subsec One}
\subsection{Subsec Two}
\subsection{Subsec Three}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For header and footer requirements, it is better to use `fancyhdr` or `titleps` as you are already using `titlesec` heavily. However, for this case if you use

```
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}
```

it will make the page number foot note size every where. You have to put this inside the definition of `oddhead` (where the page number comes in `myheadings` style. To do that add these lines in the preamble.

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\footnotesize\thepage}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that modifies the macro `\ps@myheadings`, which is defined by the `article` document class. The `etoolbox` package is loaded in order to simplify the "patching" of the `\ps@myheadings` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\ps@myheadings}{\hfil\thepage}{\hfil\footnotesize\thepage}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Hello World}
\end{document}
```